# How is my solution slower than given sample solution?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time

This was the Leet Codeproblem for Aug 26 2021.
I submitted several solutions of which this one was the best. However, it took 7 ms and when I saw sample 0 ms solution, I was shocked to find how complex the solution was and how many condition checkings were there.

---

### The Question (Editted)

Given a string of comma-separated values `preorder`, return `true` if it is a correct preorder traversal serialization of a binary tree.

It is guaranteed that each comma-separated value in the string must be either an integer or a character `'#'` representing null pointer.

---

So I posted this in [discussion](https://leetcode.com/explore/challenge/card/august-leetcoding-challenge-2021/616/week-4-august-22nd-august-28th/3920/discuss/1427223/Can-someone-explain-how-is-this-slow):

### My Solution (took 7ms)

```
class Solution
{
public:
    bool isValidSerialization(string preorder)
    {
        int c = 1;
        const int L = preorder.length();
        bool state = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < L; i++)
        {
            if (state)
            {
                state = false;
                if (!c)
                    return false;
                if (preorder[i] != '#')
                    c++;
                else
                    c--;
            }
            else
                state = preorder[i] == ',';
        }
        return !c;
    }
};
```

### Sample 0 ms solution

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isValidSerialization(string pre) {
        stack<int> s;
        if(pre.length()==1 && pre[0]=='#'){
            return true;
        }
        string num = "";
        for(int i=0; i<pre.length(); i++){
            if(pre[i]==','){
                continue;
            }
            if(s.empty() && i>0){
                return false;
            }
            if(pre[i]=='#'){
                if(s.empty()){return false;}
                s.top()--;
                while(!s.empty() && s.top()==0){
                    s.pop();
                    if(!s.empty()){s.top()--;}
                    if(!s.empty() && s.top()<0){
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                int j=i;
                while(j<pre.size() && pre[j]!=','){
                    j++;
                }
                i = j-1;
                s.push(2);
            }
            //cout << i << " -> " << s.size() << endl; 
        }
        if(s.size()>0){
            //cout << s.size() << endl;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

#### How is my program slower when it has no complex objects and fewer conditional statements??

---

As I have no hope of getting any response there, I have posted it here.

Comment: How often did you run both programs to get a reliable average runtime? Can you be sure what compiler flags were used and that they are the same for both programs? The timings on these sites can often vary, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: This was a leet code submission. I just did my solution. In the stats part I saw a sample 0 ms solution. So actually I have never run the sample solution.

Comment: I can't see the problem on leetcode (please include the problem statement in the question), but it seems the sample solution will detect some errors early and stop there, where you always do the for loop entirely.

Comment: A question should not need links to be understood. ESPECIALLY not links that requires login. [Edit] the question, and keep the links as reference.

Comment: No Alois, the algorithms are the same;; Also the link to [question](https://leetcode.com/explore/challenge/card/august-leetcoding-challenge-2021/616/week-4-august-22nd-august-28th/3920/)

Comment: Measure it yourself. You are likely to find that leetcode misrepresent the performance of the sample solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leetcode can run different solutions on different machines in different states - hence you get different results even submitting same code. Sometimes +100ms, thought c++ time is less variative than interpreted languages. Compiler flags are given in faq.
Discussions on time measurements inconsistency on leetcode: [one](https://leetcode.com/discuss/general-discussion/162462/execution-time-accuracy-and-graph), [two](https://leetcode.com/discuss/general-discussion/136683/different-run-time-with-same-code), and you can find more.